# Numpy structured arrays, selecting x,y pair with smallest x-value for several x,y pairs with the same y-value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` structured array

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = (np.array([2, 5, 8, 3, 10], dtype=np.int64),np.array([10, 10, 10, 8, 3], dtype=np.int64))

arr1_x = arr1[0]
arr1_y = arr1[1]

arr1_struct = np.empty(arr1_x.shape[0], dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int)])

arr1_struct["x"] = arr1_x
arr1_struct["y"] = arr1_y
```

As you can see, in the above structured array, I have **x** and **y** values. I would need to do the following

- Check if there are multiple **y** values that are the same
- If there are, then I would need to keep only one **x,y** value pair for that **y** value.
- The **x** value to keep would need to be the smallest **x** value among the several **x** values corresponding to the **y** value in question
- **x,y** pairs are unique and not repeated

In the above example, I would need to **keep**:

- x = 2 and y = 10 (chosen from the three **y=10** values)
- x = 3 and y = 8
- x = 10 and y = 3

The following would need to be **discarded**:

- x = 5 and y = 10
- x = 8 and y = 10

Is there a good way to go about this in `numpy`?

Comment: maybe Pandas is helpful here. `import pandas as pd; pd.Series(arr1[0]).groupby(arr1[1]).min().reset_index()`

Comment: There are a bunch of ways apparently. Had fun playing with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's simplify how you create that stuct array a bit, for no other reasons that it's grinding my gears:

```
data = np.stack(([2, 5, 8, 3, 10], [10, 10, 10, 8, 3]), axis=-1)
data = data.view(np.dtype([('x', int), ('y', int)])).ravel()
```

After sorting the data and finding the unique values of `y`, you can apply `np.minimum.reduceat` to the resulting segments of `x`:

```
data = data[np.argsort(data['y'])]
splits = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(data['y'])) + 1]
x = np.minimum.reduceat(data['x'], splits)
y = data['y'][splits]
```

Now you can re-create the array the same way as you did before:

```
result = np.stack((x, y), axis=-1).view(data.dtype).ravel()
```

This is pretty much how `np.unique` and `pd.DataFrame.groupby` work. The nice thing is that this method is insensitive to repeated pairs.

Another way to approach this is using `np.lexsort`, which can sort both columns simultaneously, so that the first element of each segment is the minimum:

```
data = data[np.lexsort((data['x'], data['y']))]
splits = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(data['y'])) + 1]
result = data[splits]
```

This method is a bit cleaner because it allows you to index directly into the data.

You can also replace the `np.diff` computations with `np.unique` using `return_index=True`. This is slightly more expensive because it sorts the array twice:

```
data = data[np.lexsort((data['x'], data['y']))]
result = data[np.unique(data['y'], return_index=True)[1]]
```